# How to expandpower series to determine residue

Tags: complex-analysis

The rational function f has the power series expansion $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nz^n$ at $z=0$ and its radius of convergence is $1$. Calculate $\operatorname{res}$z=1$f(z).$

Comment: That makes sense. Now, $f(z) = z\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^{n-1} = z\frac{d}{dz}\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$. So what's $f(z)$ explicitly?

Comment: i really don't have any more knowledge about f(z) apart from the function given above.

Comment: Don't you recognise the power series? It's a fairly often-used one, and if you recognise it, you get $f$ as a rational function in the explicit form $\dfrac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$ with polynomials $P$ and $Q$. Then finding the residue is easy.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you so much

Comment: I had an answer of 1. What is actually the meaning of the answer?

Comment: What do you mean with "What is actually the meaning of the answer?"?